# HttpMessageNotReadableException from Spring

Tags: java, android, spring

I am making an android app , which consist of a simple login using SMS verification.Using Spring MVC for webservices.

Here is my android code:

package net.simplifiedcoding.androidotp;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Creating views
    private EditText editTextUsername;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private EditText editTextPhone;
    private EditText editTextConfirmOtp;

    private AppCompatButton buttonRegister;
    private AppCompatButton buttonConfirm;

    //Volley RequestQueue
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    //String variables to hold username password and phone
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String phone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);

        buttonRegister = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        //Initializing the RequestQueue
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding a listener to button
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //This method would confirm the otp
    private void confirmOtp() throws JSONException {
        //Creating a LayoutInflater object for the dialog box
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        //Creating a view to get the dialog box
        View confirmDialog = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirm, null);

        //Initizliaing confirm button fo dialog box and edittext of dialog box
        buttonConfirm = (AppCompatButton) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonConfirm);
        editTextConfirmOtp = (EditText) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextOtp);

        //Creating an alertdialog builder
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //Adding our dialog box to the view of alert dialog
        alert.setView(confirmDialog);

        //Creating an alert dialog
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

        //Displaying the alert dialog
        alertDialog.show();

        //On the click of the confirm button from alert dialog
        buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Hiding the alert dialog
                alertDialog.dismiss();

                //Displaying a progressbar
                final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Authenticating", "Please wait while we check the entered code", false, false);

                //Getting the user entered otp from edittext
                final String otp = editTextConfirmOtp.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating an string request

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.CONFIRM_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                //if the server response is success
                                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                                    //dismissing the progressbar
                                    loading.dismiss();

                                    //Starting a new activity
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Success.class));
                                }else{
                                    //Displaying a toast if the otp entered is wrong
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong OTP Please Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    try {
                                        //Asking user to enter otp again
                                        confirmOtp();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        //Adding the parameters otp and username
                        params.put(Config.KEY_OTP, otp);
                        params.put(Config.KEY_USERNAME, username);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                //Adding the request to the queue
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });
    }


    //this method will register the user
    private void register() {

        //Displaying a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Registering", "Please wait...", false, false);
        System.out.print("sdasdasdasd");

        //Getting user data
        username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString().trim();
        System.out.print(phone);
        //Again creating the string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        try {

                            System.out.print("RESPONSE "+response);
                            //Creating the json object from the response
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                            //If it is success
                            if(jsonResponse.getString(Config.TAG_RESPONSE).equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                                //Asking user to confirm otp
                                System.out.print("monelGUPTALEMPMNNAsd\n");
                                confirmOtp();
                            }else{
                                //If not successful user may already have registered
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or Phone number already registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  paramss = new HashMap<String, String>();
                paramss.put("Content-Type","application/json");

                return paramss;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding the parameters to the request
                params.put(Config.KEY_USERNAME, username);
                params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
                params.put(Config.KEY_PHONE, phone);
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding request the the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Calling register method on register button click
        register();
    }
}
```

This is the following error i am getting :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:224) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:197) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:147) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1487) ~[jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:518) ~[jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3323) ~[jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2482) ~[jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:801) ~[jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:697) ~[jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3602) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3547) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2662) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
19:47:46.947 [http-nio-8080-exec-28] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void AnotherMVC.com.snapdeal.bull.MainController1.Register(AnotherMVC.com.snapdeal.bull.User)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]
19:47:46.947 [http-nio-8080-exec-28] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void AnotherMVC.com.snapdeal.bull.MainController1.Register(AnotherMVC.com.snapdeal.bull.User)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]
19:47:46.947 [http-nio-8080-exec-28] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void AnotherMVC.com.snapdeal.bull.MainController1.Register(AnotherMVC.com.snapdeal.bull.User)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]
19:47:46.947 [http-nio-8080-exec-28] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void AnotherMVC.com.snapdeal.bull.MainController1.Register(AnotherMVC.com.snapdeal.bull.User)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]
19:47:46.947 [http-nio-8080-exec-28] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@8dfb02f; line: 1, column: 7]
1
```

The error is showing that phone is boolean not string , but i have checked that its boolean ,

Here is my config file :

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.androidotp;

public class Config {
    //URLs to register.php and confirm.php file
    public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/FinalSmsApi/rest/requestSms/hello";

    public static final String CONFIRM_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/FinalSmsApi/rest/confirm";

    //Keys to send username, password, phone and otp
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_OTP = "otp";

    //JSON Tag from response from server
    public static final String TAG_RESPONSE= "ErrorMessage";
}
```

Comment: Unrecognized token 'phone': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') your service is accepting only Boolean values for this tag.!?

Comment: its expecting String , nowhere it's written boolean

Comment: problem should be in your webservice maybe.!

Comment: no answer here?